# NDVI Value of a pixel calculation - Python

Tags: python, pixel, calculation

I am trying to extract an array of ndvi values for each pixel of an blue-filtered image (.jpg format). I used the NDVI=(arrayR-arrayB)/(arrayR+arrayB) however as a result I get a long list of arrays containing different values:

```
array([ 0.44554455, 0.48387097, 0.47368421, ..., 0.14 , 0.14285714, 0.14285714]), 
array([ 0.45454545, 0.49450549, 0.48387097, ..., 0.14583333, 0.13207547, 0.14583333]), 
array([ 0.48314607, 0.46391753, 0.45454545, ..., 0.14583333, 0.13461538, 0.14583333]), 
array([ 0.40186916, 0.44554455, 0.46938776, ..., 0.125 , 0.12280702, 0.18681319]), 
array([ 0.40540541, 0.46391753, 0.49473684, ..., 0.16666667, 0.16 , 0.16363636]), 
array([ 0.39823009, 0.42056075, 0.47474747, ..., 0.17021277, 0.20454545, 0.15789474]), 
array([ 0.51111111, 0.47916667, 0.46 , ..., 0.1588785 , 0.16831683, 0.16190476]),
```

The code used to get these results is:

```
from PIL import Image
from sense_hat import SenseHat
import numpy as numpy
img= Image.open('foo.jpg')
imgR, imgB, imgG = img.split() #get channels
arrR = numpy.asarray(imgR).astype('float64')
arrB = numpy.asarray(imgB).astype('float64')
num   = (arrR - arrB)
denom = (arrR + arrB)
if denom.any() == 0:    #preventing division by zero.
  denom = [0.000001, 0.000001]
arr_ndvi = num/denom
```

Which is actually the NDVI value of each pixel? Is it the average of the numbers inside each array?

Comment: Show some actual code

Comment: That being said, the NDVI array will have as many elements as your input image has pixels. You need to do a little reading on the basics of the tools you are using if you are having trouble understanding what an array is and how addition and division work on it.

Comment: Thank you for commenting! I have added the code used.

Comment: Why do you do `list(arr_ndvi)` when you print?

Comment: Do you understand what your intermediate arrays contain, and what the result contains?

Comment: Since `arrR` and `arrB` are Numpy 2D arrays, `list(arr_ndvi)` returns instead a list of rows of the NDVI matrix, so each value in each array is the NDVI of the corresponding pixel, e.g. `arr_ndvi[0,0] == 0.44554455` is the NDVI of the top-left pixel.

Comment: Show the relevant imports. What is `Image`? What type of data does it contain? Do you really  need to convert to `float`? If you do, why not do it in one step with a `dtype` argument to `asarray`?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov. The original array is already a sequence of rows. It's pretty clear that you understand what's going on. these questions I'm asking are meant for OP only really, to assess what they know and don't know. The problem here is that the basic answer is trivial, which means that there is a large gap in OP's knowledge to fill in. Estimating the size of the gap will tell me if I should direct them to a tutorial or answer the question.

Comment: Are you sure that completely failing to compute the NDVI when you have pure green pixels is what you want to do? I mean as opposed to just setting those pixels to zero or some flag value in the output.

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't a `NameError` you aren't telling us about? `denom` is used before it is assigned. That usually doesn't fly.

Comment: @Tas. Please don't take my questions the wrong way. I would really like to help you but I need to know where to start. Normally I'd vote to close a question like this down and move on, but NDVI and GNDVI are subjects dear to my heart.

Comment: Hello, thanks for all your replies and I really appreciate that you would like to help me!  I will be providing a full answer when I get back home, to be able to include as much information and code as possible!

Comment: Alright, let me begin by saying what is the purpose of this code: I want to get the percentage of the vegetation of an area that has been photographed from air, with a camera that has been modified to take near-infared photos, and equipped with a filter like this: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0198/8618/products/filter-tweezers_1024x1024.jpg?v=1496430741 (1st part of answer)

Comment: After a bit of research I decided to take pictures taken by that modified camera, and make a python code that would analyse them and get the percentage I wanted. I am no expert at python, and I used the NumPy and Pillow modules, as I found that these can help me accomplish what I wanted. Now to your questions: 1) The intermediate arrays contain the RGB values of each pixel, I believe. 2)from PIL import Image
import numpy as numpy 3)I read somewhere that I need to convert to float, that's why I did it. 4)You are right, unfortunately I did not post the updated code, which I will now (part 2)

Comment: Maybe using vstack to merge all the arrays into one, and filter the values above 0.5 (a sample vegetation threshold) would do the trick?